# Array output has failed since updating to PHP 7.3

Tags: php, arrays

I have a block of code that outputs attribute information that is stored in an array. The site was running PHP 5.6, and it worked fine. Since upgrading to PHP 7.3 this has stopped working.

The code in question is

```
<?php
$attribute_list = '';
if (isset($product['attributes']) && sizeof($product['attributes']) > 0 ) {
  foreach ($product['attributes'] as $option_id => $attribute) {
    $attribute_list[$option_id] = array($attribute['products_options_name'], $attribute['products_options_values_name']);
  }

  if (is_array($attribute_list) && sizeof($attribute_list) > 0) {
    $attribute_list = ' [' . $attribute_list[1][1] . '] ' . ORDER_INFO_MODIFICATION_NAME . '[' . $attribute_list[2][1] . ' ' . $attribute_list[4][1] . ' ' . $attribute_list[5][1] . '] ' . ORDER_INFO_MODIFICATION_DEPARTURE . '[' . $attribute_list[6][1] . '] ' . ORDER_INFO_MODIFICATION_DATE_OF_USE . '[' . $attribute_list[7][1] . ']';
  }
}
?>
<a href="<?php echo $product['linkProductsName']; ?>"><span id="cartImage" class="back"><?php echo $product['productsImage']; ?></span><span id="cartProdTitle"><?php echo $product['showFixedQuantityAmount'] . ' x ' . $product['productsName'] . $attribute_list . '<span class="alert bold">' . $product['flagStockCheck'] . '</span>'; ?></span></a>
```

It should give an output like
[Adult] Name[Mr Web Tester] Departure[31/10/2019] Date of Use[29/11/2019]

But instead I just get AA AAAA

var_export($product['attributes']); is

```
array ( 1 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'Adult/Child', 'options_values_id' => '2', 'products_options_values_name' => 'Adult', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), 2 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'Title', 'options_values_id' => '5', 'products_options_values_name' => 'Mr', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), 4 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'First Name', 'options_values_id' => '0', 'products_options_values_name' => 'JSWeb', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), 5 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'Last Name', 'options_values_id' => '0', 'products_options_values_name' => 'Tester', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), 6 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'Leave Home?', 'options_values_id' => '0', 'products_options_values_name' => '30/11/2019', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), 7 => array ( 'products_options_name' => 'Date of use', 'options_values_id' => '0', 'products_options_values_name' => '09/12/2019', 'options_values_price' => '0.0000', 'price_prefix' => '', ), )
```

If I echo the content of `$option_id`, `$attribute['products_options_name']`, and `$attribute['products_options_values_name']` they are all correct.

I had a look on php.net and didn't see anything specifically related to PHP 7.3 for array().

Any suggestions on what might be wrong here?

Comment: Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled? _“The array content for the test was”_ - please show a `var_export` of that instead, then people can easily copy&paste it to have testable code directly.

Comment: `$attribute_list` cannot be both a string and an array.

Comment: @04FS Error logging is enabled on the site, but there is nothing in the log.
I'll update the question with the output of var_export($product['attributes']);

Comment: My guess is PHP7 is handling he `$attribute_list[$option_id] = ...` line differently as it's earlier defined as a string. You could make it work by removing that first line, but that'd still be confusing code; just rename either of the two variables.

Comment: @Jeto You are spot on there. I changed that first line, and other uses of it to $attribute_list_output and it works again now. Something for me to look out for in future. Thanks for that